# Enable PHP Firebird connection

Tags: php, connection, firebird

I have to create PHP web service with `Firebird db`. This is the first time I configure connection with this db and I cant get it right.

I followed every instructions from php manual site, copied neccesry dll files to `win/syste32` folder etc. and it's not working.

I dont understand this part:

```
Use --with-pdo-firebird[=DIR]
```

to install the PDO Firebird extension, where the optional `[=DIR]` is the Firebird base install directory.

```
$ ./configure --with-pdo-firebird
```

Where should I run this?

Answer (score 2):

These instructions only apply to building PHP from source.

On Windows, you should find that a `php_pdo_firebird.dll` file is included in the installation package in the `ext` directory, all that is required is to uncomment/add the following line in php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
```

You can then check that the driver is enabled in `phpinfo()`, `php -i` or with `PDO::getAvailableDrivers()`.

Comment: Its uncommented but in php info states that PDO drivers are enabled for mysql, sqlite only

Comment: @VladimirErakovic have you verified that the `php_pdo_firebird.dll` file exists and is in the path specified by `extension_dir`? Have you also verified that PHP is loading the correct ini file? (this can be checked with `phpinfo()`/`php -i`). Note also that under apache you will need to restart Apache, and under FPM you will need to restart FPM before any changes to the ini file will take effect.

Comment: Make sure also that Firebird client library fbclient.dll is available for loading by php_pdo_firebird.dll as it is a required component for a proper work.