# Trying to add the firebird extension to PDO with no luck. I have a RHEL7 server

Tags: php, pdo, firebird, rhel7

I've been trying to add the Firebird extension to PDO with no luck. I have a RHEL7 server, I ran `./configure --with-firebird` successfully, ran the `make` command, and `make install` successfully.

If I type

```
php -i | grep PDO
```

I get the following:

```
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => firebird, sqlite
PDO_Firebird
PDO Driver for Firebird/InterBase => enabled
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

However, when going to my site's `phptest.php` file it only shows

```
mysql
sqlite
```

I guess I'm missing one last step, but I don't know what.

Comment: I suspect u have to add one more cmdline option. It seems you installed firebird API libraries but not firebird-to-PDO bridge ones. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735252/enable-php-firebird-connection

Comment: this also lists another command line option http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.php

Comment: Your question helped me, I solved this problem just rebooting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try running slightly different command

```
  ./configure --with-firebird --with-pdo-firebird
```

Then find `phph.ini` (or the file that acts like that in Linux platform) and enable (de-comment?) the line like `extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll` ( in Linux it probably would be like `libphp_pdo_firebird.so` or something, see for the specific files your building process generate).

See also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.php
- [Enable PHP Firebird connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735252/enable-php-firebird-connection)

Comment: hi, would this try to install firebird on my system?  is it necesary for pdo_firebird to work correctly?  I wouldn't want to mess up my system since its a live server.

Comment: @sfiguer It should not try, it only installs PHP modules. Firebird server is a separate software and should be installed separately.

Comment: @sfiguer NExt thing, you NEVER EVER "try" things on live servers. IF you are not sure what you do, either hire RHEL7 professional, or make a clone of the server into some virtual machine and do your "tries" on the virtual clone. Only reconfigure any live server when you know perfectly what you do step by step